# Jackson + Jersey returns List with root name "List"

Tags: list, element, jersey, root, jackson

Im currently trying to create a system for serializing POJO objects using Jackson and Jersey, here my resource:

```
@Path("/OrganicasFuncao")
```

public class OrganicasFuncaoResource {

```
public OrganicasFuncaoResource() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/getAllOrganicasFuncao")

public List<OrganicaFuncaoMobileEntity> getOrganicasFuncao(){

     List<OrganicaFuncaoMobileEntity> organicas; organicas= new ArrayList<OrganicaFuncaoMobileEntity>();

    //dummy data
    organicas.add(fillOrganicaFuncao(111,123,"Função Assim","2010-12-23"));
    organicas.add(fillOrganicaFuncao(113,124,"Função Assada","2000-05-21"));
    organicas.add(fillOrganicaFuncao(113,125,"Função Meio termo","2002-12-23"));
    organicas.add(fillOrganicaFuncao(112,126,"Função Mal Passada","2011-06-14"));
    organicas.add(fillOrganicaFuncao(112,127,"Função Bem Passada","2006-02-01"));
    organicas.add(fillOrganicaFuncao(111,128,"Função Crua","2003-04-07"));
    organicas.add(fillOrganicaFuncao(113,127,"Função Queimadinha","2006-02-01"));
    organicas.add(fillOrganicaFuncao(113,128,"Função Tostada","2003-04-07"));


    return organicas;
}

private OrganicaFuncaoMobileEntity fillOrganicaFuncao(int id, int idOrg, String designacao, String dataAlteracao){

    OrganicaFuncaoMobileEntity orgFunc= new OrganicaFuncaoMobileEntity();
    orgFunc.setDataAlteracao(dataAlteracao);
    orgFunc.setDesignacao(designacao);
    orgFunc.setId(id);
    orgFunc.setIdOrganica(idOrg);

    return orgFunc;
}
```

}

This returns:

{
  "List" : [ {
    "designacao" : "FunÃ§Ã£o Assim",
    "idOrganica" : 123,
    "dataAlteracao" : "2010-12-23",
    "id" : 111
  }, {
    "designacao" : "FunÃ§Ã£o Assada",
    "idOrganica" : 124,
    "dataAlteracao" : "2000-05-21",
    "id" : 113
  }, {
    "designacao" : "FunÃ§Ã£o Meio termo",
    "idOrganica" : 125,
    "dataAlteracao" : "2002-12-23",
    "id" : 113
  }, {
    "designacao" : "FunÃ§Ã£o Mal Passada",
    "idOrganica" : 126,
    "dataAlteracao" : "2011-06-14",
    "id" : 112
  }, {
    "designacao" : "FunÃ§Ã£o Bem Passada",
    "idOrganica" : 127,
    "dataAlteracao" : "2006-02-01",
    "id" : 112
  }, {
    "designacao" : "FunÃ§Ã£o Crua",
    "idOrganica" : 128,
    "dataAlteracao" : "2003-04-07",
    "id" : 111
  }, {
    "designacao" : "FunÃ§Ã£o Queimadinha",
    "idOrganica" : 127,
    "dataAlteracao" : "2006-02-01",
    "id" : 113
  }, {
    "designacao" : "FunÃ§Ã£o Tostada",
    "idOrganica" : 128,
    "dataAlteracao" : "2003-04-07",
    "id" : 113
  } ]
}

How can i change the "List" name with some of my own? i tried using several annotations like @jsonTypeName or @jsonTypeInfo, but that didnt work....

Comment: Have you configure Jersey to use Jackson, because, by default, it use JAXB. The kind of output you give seems to be related to JAXB, not to Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency for Jackson. Jackson is a good JSON serializer/deserializer which Jersey supports. It does not require any annotations on the serialized/deserialized classes, just define them as "structs":

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

It does not need getters and setters if you let your fields be `public`. The dependencies you need can be found here: http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=com.fasterxml.jackson.core. No need for additional configuration, Jersey will detect it if it is on classpath.

The problem you are having is probably caused by Jerseys default OOTB JSON serialization/deserialization.